# Number of decimals of a double in json-c/json.h

Tags: c, json, format

I need to use very small doubles to be used in a JSON object. The output of the array is something similar to:

```
{"array":[[1,0.050000],[2,0.030000]...]}
```

The code I'm using is:

```
json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();
json_object *jarray1 = json_object_new_array();
json_object *jarray2 = json_object_new_array();
...
// in a for loop:
    json_object *int0 = json_object_new_int (integer_num);
    json_object *db0 = json_object_new_double (double_num);
    json_object_array_add(jarray1, int0);
    json_object_array_add(jarray1, db0);
    json_object_array_add(jarray2, jarray1);
...
json_object_object_add(jobj,"array", jarray2);
```

This works fine with the numbers shown above. The problem is that when the numbers are smaller, p.e. 1.6E-10, the output is:

```
{"array":[[1,0.000000],[2,0.000000]...]}
```

So is the same as sending '0' and this is not desired. I've tried converting the double to text as:

```
sprintf(str,"%.15f", double_num);
db0 = json_object_new_string(str);
```

But then the output is:

```
{"array":[[1,"0.000000000093575"],[2,"0.000000000091282"]...]}
```

and I need to remove those quotation marks. Is there another way to increase the number of decimals in the output array or to use the scientific notation (1.6E-10)?

Comment: How do you ask your program to do an output?

Comment: print_json_object(jobj, "output in plaintext");

Comment: You can try to change the double format with `json_c_set_serialization_double_format("%g", JSON_C_OPTION_GLOBAL);`

Comment: I've tried with:
json_object_set_serializer(db0, json_object_userdata_to_json_string, "%g", NULL);
but not sure how to deal with "json_object_userdata_to_json_string"

Comment: error: ‘json_object_userdata_to_json_string’ undeclared

Comment: Did you try Mathieu's suggestion?

Comment: yes, and this is the output after compiling:

server.c:1320:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘json_c_set_serialization_double_format’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              json_c_set_serialization_double_format("%g", JSON_C_OPTION_GLOBAL);
              ^
server.c:1320:59: error: ‘JSON_C_OPTION_GLOBAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
              json_c_set_serialization_double_format("%g", JSON_C_OPTION_GLOBAL);

Comment: From what I've understood I need to implement a custom serialization function ("json_object_userdata_to_json_string"), that is called when using  "json_object_set_serializer". I tried by myself, but it's not working properly right now. Any suggestion on how to do it properly will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I got around a similar issue by using this function to format my double.

```
#include <json.h>
    struct json_object* json_object_new_double_fmt(double d, const char *fmt)
    
        {
          char tmp[128];
          snprintf(tmp, 128, fmt, d);
          return(json_object_new_double_s(d, tmp));
        }
```

eg:

```
  json_object_object_add(jobjPressure, "Pr", json_object_new_double_fmt((double) pressuredata->pressure, "%0.3f"));
```

I could not see why 'json_object_new_double_s()' needs the first double argument because the second char string just seems to get used 'as is'. Not sure if this is a bug or my mis use of the function. But I can't find any meaningful documentation or example code.  Seems to do the job though.